# On-swipe makes the text not selectable in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing mobile app using ionic framework. I have a long text and i am showing it as e-book in e-reader swiping left and right.
At the same moment i need to select a part of the text and at the beginning i did adding style: -webkit-user-select: auto;.
But now i have added the swipe functions and it blocks the event of selectable text.
my piece of code looks like that:

```
<ion-content class="padding projects selected">
        <div class="list" id="text" on-swipe-left="swipeLeft()" on-swipe-right="swipeRight()">
    </div>     
</ion-content>
```

Comment: What is the text issue?  Seems like an issue with passing the data around with Angular, not an issue with Ionic which is what your code is focused on showing.

Comment: @Chris. Before using on-swipe-left/right i could select the text in the view and copy all other thing, but aftr adding swipe i can not select the text.

Comment: I would need to see an example of how you are showing the text to help you.

Comment: @ChrisStory here is the examples for two conditions, [Without swipe](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOqzvR) in this example we can select the text. In the second example [With swipe](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvoVXr) on-swipe-left/right is given and we can't select the text

Comment: Ah.  You question now makes sense to me with an example.  You are talking about using the mouse's ability to select the text through a mouse drag.  I will work on this a little bit an see if I can get an answer.  I imagine ionic is blocking the default behavior with their directive.

Comment: possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829222/ionic-1-cant-select-text-on-ie?noredirect=1#comment70846569_41829222