# Ionic 1 - Can't select text on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, ionic-framework

By adding :

```
.scroll {
  -webkit-user-select: text !important;
  -moz-user-select: text !important;
  -ms-user-select: text !important;
  user-select: text !important;
}
```

I can select text on desktop browsers **except on IE**.

I figure out that when I comment my import :

```
//require('ionic-npm/js/ionic');
```

On IE I can select text but I need ionic so I can't comment that line. Also I don't what to touch to ionic.js.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365824/unable-to-select-the-text-in-ie-browsers-in-ionic-frame-work

Comment: I saw but it's not resolved...

Comment: Have you tried  -ms-user-select: auto;?

Comment: on body and .scroll yes and doesn't work

Comment: have you tried the code in my answer?

Comment: yes not working

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:

> forum.ionicframework: How to make text selectable?

Link: [Original forum Post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-make-text-selectable/4384)

Are you referring to using this technique on mobile or desktop?

On mobile it still seems to be working for me, but If it isn't working for you on desktop, that might be because it doesn't work if the user can use their mouse to click-and-drag to scroll the page. To disable this type of scrolling you can either enable overflow-scroll on your content:

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
```

Or you can disable the mouse click-and-drag-to-scroll events by further changing ionic.js like so...

Add 'return;' to the beginning of this mouseDown function:

```
self.mouseDown = function(e) {
if ( ionic.tap.ignoreScrollStart(e) || e.target.tagName === 'SELECT' ) {
  return;
}
self.doTouchStart(getEventTouches(e), e.timeStamp);

if( !ionic.tap.isTextInput(e.target) ) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
mousedown = true;
};
```

So that it looks like this:

```
self.mouseDown = function(e) {

return; // <--- This disables all mouseDown events from scrolling the page

if ( ionic.tap.ignoreScrollStart(e) || e.target.tagName === 'SELECT' ) {
  return;
}
self.doTouchStart(getEventTouches(e), e.timeStamp);

if( !ionic.tap.isTextInput(e.target) ) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
mousedown = true;
};
```

This change makes it so you can still use the ionic scroll features with your mouse wheel, but disables mouse click-and-drag scrolling so that you can use your mouse to select text.

Comment: Thanks but I want to use that selection only on desktop and doesn't want to change ionic.js. Here you have to change it

Comment: yes but what if I upgrade my ionic lib ? I'll forget that change and if  it's not me on the project the futur developer will have to search again on the web why that doesn't work and maybe push in prod before check that regression

Comment: I know it's sad but I would like a clean fix :p

Comment: Make the suggested fix and leave a visibile comment somewhere. Maybe also renaming the lib file, for the sake of clear.

Comment: Hmm... the lib is on my node_modules and node_modules are not shared on git so if I update the lib my collaborators will not have that change...

Comment: Put in other place in you folder and put on .git